# NSwag Swagger multiple request body models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, swashbuckle, nswag

I know I can specify different `[SwaggerResponse(...)]` attributes for different HTTP codes. Can I specify multiple `[SwaggerRequest(typeof(MyRequestBody1))]`:

```
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerRequest(typeof(MyRequestBody1))]
[SwaggerRequest(typeof(MyRequestBody2))]
public Task PostAsync([FromBody] JObject body) 
{
    ...
}
```

What are the available NSwag options for me?

I need to make sure those models will be listed for this endpoint. I have 80 different models to process, so creating individual endpoints is not an option.

Comment: See https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/Inheritance